Approaches and problems with massively concurrent processing using concurrent.futures and/or asyncio
I want to run billions of IO-bound tasks across a pool of thousands of threads. These are my challenges:

Reduce memory usage. The thread pool from concurrent.futures uses an unbound queue. Too many submissions and memory usage balloons but too few and not enough work is accomplished.
Collect results. Neither the pool nor its context manager store completed futures, so collecting results isn't necessary to reduce memory usage. I would like the option of collecting results if at some future time I need them.
Handle exceptions. I would like python exceptions in any of the tasks to be propagated to the main thread.
Incorporate asyncio via loop.run_in_executor()

Each future from concurrent.futures can have an add_done_callback that collects the result and handles any exceptions. Exceptions raised within these callbacks are ignored, but since callbacks run from the main thread, exceptions can be stored as a global variable and re-raised from the submission loop. This doesn't help in reducing memory usage, but I haven't figured out how to do that even through asyncio (see below).
To incorporate asyncio I create a consumer task and a producer task. The producer submits callables to the loop's executor in a synchronous loop, placing the resulting futures onto an unbound queue.
The consumer maintains a set of pending futures, awaiting the first result from either that set or the queue. It awaits the result of asyncio.wait() over both the queue and a second asyncio.wait() coroutine over the set of pending futures. If the result comes from the queue, it adds it to the set and resumes waiting. If the result is a completed future, it processes the results and handles exceptions before resuming the wait. The task is complete when the queue shuts down.
Am I making this overly convoluted? Is there a simpler approach?
I haven't figured out a neat way to reduce memory usage. The best I can come up with is to check the thread pool's _work_queue.qsize(), and if it exceeds a threshold, to simply await asyncio.sleep(<small number>). Surely there must be a better way?
